# How to receive a message via Push in Cloud Pub/Sub using Java

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to implement Google Cloud Pub/Sub to receive a message(via Push) using Java but I couldn't find documentation for Java.

I am able to receive message via pull, also any leads to setup and test Endpoint locally would be very helpful.

I have verified and added domain as Endpoint wondering what to do next to start receiving message at that endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

A push endpoint in any language is simply an HTTP web server that can receive POST requests with a JSON body of the following form:

```
{
  "message": {
    "attributes": {
      "key": "value"
    },
    "data": "SGVsbG8gQ2xvdWQgUHViL1N1YiEgSGVyZSBpcyBteSBtZXNzYWdlIQ==",
    "messageId": "136969346945"
  },
  "subscription": "projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription"
}
```

Documentation for registering your push endpoint is [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push).  There are plenty of Java web server options available such as [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/index.html) and [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you were able to receive the message via pull, do you use some kind of scheduler in the Java app. to pull the message from pub/sub periodically?

If you are still looking for the answer, you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages) the way to write a push end point (sample) and a way to invoke the same from local.

Hope this helps.